# Let $T\in L(V,W)$. Prove that $T$ is invertible $\iff [T]_{B'B}$ invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ a basis of $V$ and $B'$ a basis of $W$. Suppose $\dim(V)=\dim(W)<\infty $. Let $T\in L(V,W)$. Prove that $T$ is invertible $\iff [T]_{B'B}$ invertible.

---

**Proof**

Set $A=[T]_{B'B}$. We have that $T(x)=0\iff Ax=0 \iff x=0$. Therefore $\ker T=\{0\}$ and thus $T$ is invertible.

Conversely suppose $T$ invertible. Then, $Ax=0\iff T(x)=0\iff x=0$. Then $\ker A=\{0\}$ Does it work ?

Comment: You might have the right thought in mind, but your writing is not impeccable.